# Unable to set ref due to error "TS2339: Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Y' " inside a react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Using TypeScript, I have the following props `type` and component `class` defined:

```
type AnimatedElementProps = {
  node: HTMLElement;
  Svg(props: SVGProps): JSX.Element,
 };

class AnimatedElement extends React.Component<AnimatedElementProps> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.node = undefined;
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
          <div
              ref={(n) => this.node = n}
              className={styles.animatedElement}
              style={defaultStyle}
          >
            <Svg/>
          </div>
    );
  };
}
```

I want to capture the `ref` to the div element inside the `render` function,  however I keep getting:

> error TS2339: Property 'node' does not exist on type 'AnimatedElement'.

What is the proper way to define and initialise a custom class variable inside a react component using TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then this looks like a case of a missing field in your class definition. You should find that declaring the field:

```
private node?: HTMLElement;
```

in your class definition resolves the issue:

```
class AnimatedElement extends React.Component<AnimatedElementProps> {

  private node?: HTMLElement; /* <-- Add this */

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.node = undefined;
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
          <div
              ref={(n) => this.node = n}
              className={styles.animatedElement}
              style={defaultStyle}
          >
            <Svg/>
          </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Also note, the `node?` syntax with question mark. The `?` is short hand stating that the field can have type `HTMLElement` or `undefined`. This is necessary, seeing that you're initially assigning `undefined` to the field in your class constructor.